# Postfix main.cf - certain lines dissapear - breaks postfix

Tags: configuration, postfix

I have two VoIP freepbx servers. I setup server A and cloned it to Server B and changed the hostname and IP.

The postfix configuration file on server B seems to get like 5 lines deleted which breaks postfix which causes a log file over almost 100GB's to fill up root partition. (Failing over and over to send an e-mail)

I have fixed this by just cat'ing a new postfix config file every 30 minutes, but I would love to know what is the problem and how is it happening.

I have made the file 400 w/ postfix:nobody permissions, but it still happens!

```
[root@voip2 postfix]# ll main.cf
-r-------- 1 postfix nobody 1226 Apr  4 12:30 main.cf
```

Here is the main.cf and how I installed it:

```
cat << 'EOL' >/etc/postfix/main.cf
#
# PostFix Config

##Modify Below [HOSTNAME]
myhostname = [HOSTNAME]

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
relayhost = [smtp.hmc1.comcast.net]:587
mydomain = domain.com
mydestination = $myhostname $myhostname.$mydomain localhost.$mydomain localhost
sender_canonical_maps = static:$myhostname@$mydomain
EOL
```

Here is what my main.cf looks like after it gets randomly messed up, this is consistently how it looks as well:

```
#
# PostFix Config

##Modify Below [HOSTNAME]


smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache





mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical


mydestination = $myhostname $myhostname.$mydomain localhost.$mydomain localhost
sender_canonical_maps = static:$myhostname@$mydomain
```

Here is the tail end of the log file from overnight: (This happened over night while I was gone)

```
Apr  4 12:30:03 voip2 postfix/master[21006]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  4 12:59:25 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[22506]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Apr  4 12:59:25 voip2 postfix/master[21006]: terminating on signal 15
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2374]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2384]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/access
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2385]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/canonical
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2386]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/canonical.db
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2387]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/generic
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2388]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/header_checks
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2389]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/main.cf
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2390]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/master.cf
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2391]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/relocated
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2392]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/sasl
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2393]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2394]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd.db
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2395]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/transport
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2396]: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/virtual
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[2411]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr  4 13:00:57 voip2 postfix/master[2412]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  4 13:21:15 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[8412]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Apr  4 13:21:15 voip2 postfix/master[2412]: reload -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr  5 00:00:01 voip2 postfix/sendmail[6683]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
Apr  5 00:01:01 voip2 postfix/sendmail[6737]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
Apr  5 00:06:24 voip2 postfix/sendmail[7139]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
Apr  5 05:31:28 voip2 postfix/postfix-script[23065]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Apr  5 05:31:28 voip2 postfix/master[2412]: reload -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
[root@voip2 log]#
```

Edit: It seems this is more a FreePBX issue, I have tracked down the "culprit" and it happens when I restore a TGZ File from server A to server B

Comment: Server configurations do not normally corrupt themselves. Also what is with those permission problems? Perhaps `sysdig fd.name contains /etc/postfix` will reveal what is making the changes.

Comment: I'm going to make everything root currently it's owned by postfix, I'm not familiar with sysdig I should mention I'm on Centos 6

Comment: Permissions 0400 and owners `postfix:nobody` for `main.cf` are wrong and breaks Postfix. `/etc/postfix` not owned by `root` is also wrong and breaks Postfix. Don't assume you understand Postfix security better than the author of Postfix. FWIW.

Comment: It's never broken postfix for me, but based on logs I agree it should be root not postfix